# best structure for a customized virto commerce

Tags: virtocommerce

Any suggestions of how to structure my solutions when developing custom Modules and frontend?
I.e. Should I just clone the repoy and add my modules and change web.config  with transform files directly in the repo. Will a future pull working well then? any ideas for simple developing and simple upgrade?

Or is it wrong aproach. Should i use azure deploy script/ slot settings and call virto api to add virto modules...

Comment: ok i saw thar virto has updated is documentation :) http://docs.virtocommerce.com/display/vc2devguide/Developing+a+custom+solution

Answer (score 1):

ok i saw thar virto has updated its documentation
http://docs.virtocommerce.com/display/vc2devguide/Developing+a+custom+solution